# Laravel Notification not broadcasting without any error?

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm trying to implement a notification system with Laravel and Vue JS. I implemented everything and it needs to be work but Notification class is not broadcasting.

.env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=40xxxx
PUSHER_KEY=5a6axxxxxx
PUSHER_SECRET=b35xxxxxx
```

Already run those commands below:

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~2.6"
```

in app.js (uncommented)

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

**BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.*', function ($user, $userID) {
            return (int) $user->id === (int) $userID;
        });
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
 window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
 window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '5a6axxxxxx',
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true,
    authEndpoint: "/broadcasting/auth"
 });
 window.Pusher.log = function(message){
    window.console.log(message);
 }
 window.Echo.private('App.User.1')
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification.type);
 });
```

No errors in Laravel log. In the parallel, I am checking on Pusher's  Debug Console only connect and disconnect requests on there. Why it's not pushing any kind of error and why it's not working properly?

Comment: Where's your Javascript?

Comment: updated the question. Sorry I forgot to add it

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem. How did you fix yours?

Comment: Same problem with me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case, the cause of the problem was the placement of the `User` model by namespace `App\Models\User`.
The first way to solve this problem is to:

in BroadcastServiceProvider.php or routes/channels.php (if laravel 5.7+)

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.*', function ($user, $userID) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $userID;
});
```

The second way to solve this problem is:

In `User` model add method

```
public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn() {
    return 'users.'.$this->id;
}
```

and in BroadcastServiceProvider.php or routes/channels.php (if laravel 5.7+)

```
Broadcast::channel('users.{user_id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You will also need to configure and run a [queue worker](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues). All event broadcasting is done via queued jobs so that the response time of your application is not seriously affected by events being broadcast.

Read more in docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#queue-configuration

It might be due to because all broadcasting is done via queued jobs so run queue work command

```
php artisan queue:work
```

If you found this helpful so please vote : ) happy codding

Edit: This solution works but not perfact solution either I not remember why I was write that, but the right solution is that you have to uncomment serviceProvider in config/app.php

[image: app.php]